# Dealing with optional field with lihaoyi ujson

Tags: scala, upickle

I want to use ujson of the [upickle library](http://www.lihaoyi.com/upickle/#uJson) to extract an optional string from a json document. In some documents the json field exists, in others not.

When acessing the field and the field does not exist I get a NoSuchElementException:

```
val json = ujson.read(jsonString)
json("attributename").str

results in: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: attributename
```

What is the idiomatic way to deal with optional json attributes in ujson?

Comment: there is now a pr to fix this in the future: https://github.com/com-lihaoyi/upickle/issues/528

Answer (score 4):

If you want to return default value in case of any exception you can use `Try` with `getOrElse`:

```
val result = Try(json("attributename").str).getOrElse("defaultValue")
```

The result will be value of `attributename` key or `defaultValue` string if there is no such key.

Answer (score 2):

I think the idiomatic way is to have a case class instead of going against the JSON AST manually.

In your case class you could then have an `Option[String]` field.

```
case class MyModel( attributeName: Option[String] )
implicit val rw: ReadWriter[MyModel] = macroRW

read[MyModel](jsonString)
```

But from the looks of it, you could do

```
json.obj.value.get("attributename").map(_.str)
```

to get an `Option[String]` back.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget, a json is an object.

So we can check it like this:

```
val json = ujson.read(jsonString)
if (json.obj.get("attributename").nonEmpty) {
  json("attributename").str
  ...
}
```

And btw, you can get the keySet like this:

```
json.obj.keySet
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [liahoy](https://gitter.im/lihaoyi/upickle?at=5dc02e3e9c39821509dff871)

> the canonical way is to add `None` defaults

for [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gYvQ2d5uRyCW3J3aWHAAwA),

```
import upickle.default._

case class User(name: String, age: Option[Int] = None)
implicit val userRW: ReadWriter[User] = macroRW
read[User]("""{ "name": "Picard" }""")
```

outputs

```
res0: User = User(Picard,None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but, I was looking the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/lihaoyi/upickle/blob/master/ujson/src/ujson/Value.scala)
It seems at line 62 and from line 87 till line 99, it just call `x.obj(i)`.

It doesn't perform any check, and just call it. This lead to a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` because trying to access without a check. I didn't see around any version to get the Option, or to even perform a check if this value exists.

I would suggest to go via a Try/Success/Failure idiom on scala

```
val tryAttr = Try{json("attributename").str}
tryAttr match {
  case Success(_) => doYourThing
  case Failure(t: NoSuchElementException) => DoSomethingElse
}
```